# Unwanted <end> tag appearing in email sent using SmtpClient

Tags: c#, outlook, html-email, smtpclient

Where is this unwanted `<end>` tag coming from in the body of my email? How can I get rid of it? I'm sending a basic email using the SMTPClient with IsBodyHtml set to true.

[image: unwantedEndTag]

Here is my code:

```
private void SendEmail(OnHoldViewModel vm)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxx@xxxx.com", "To"));
        msg.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@xxxx.com", "From");
        msg.Subject = "Unwanted <End> tag";
        msg.Body = "<span>TESTING EMAIL</span>";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Port = 25;
        client.Host = "10.10.10.4";
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = false;

        try
        {
            client.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What client? I have been seeing this in outlook...

Comment: Outlook 2016 from Office 365

Comment: That's not a tag, and it's not part of your email. It's just part of how Outlook displays the desktop alert for very short messages.

Comment: Can it be removed?

Comment: No. Again, it's not part of your email. Clients can display things like that however they want. You can trick Outlook by adding more to the message, but that's it.

Comment: I think the downvote was a bit harsh, he did not know, thus a question.

Comment: @elixenide is right! I made my body longer and it disappeared